# What is the default password for Oracle 19c?

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I have installed the latest Oracle 19c for Windows 64 bit from [here](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/oracle-database-software-downloads.html). Now, when I tried access the oracle server, it is prompting for username and password. I have tried to put `system` as username and `change_on_install` as password but getting below error.

[image]

I tried using /nolog and connect as sysdba but got the same error.

[image]

During install, I did not get any option to create user account. Can anyone let me know what is the default username and password?

Comment: There is no default password. It's specified when you install Oracle.

Comment: I figured out the problem. I installed grid_home instead of db_home.

Answer (score 3):

On windows, just like on the Linux command line set environment variables such as ORACLE_HOME, ORACLE_SID and PATH.
Construct your PATH such that it uses your ORACLE_HOME/bin as the first location.

Now sqlplus / as sysdba
should give you a connection, if you do this using the account that installed oracle. If the database is running.

If not, on windows first check that the oracle service for this database is started.

There is no default password but with this connection you can alter the password of any user to whatever you want.

Comment: I figured out the problem. I installed grid_home instead of db_home.